# EF Core Reading Connection String From User Secret Using Class Library Project and DB Scaffolding

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two projects, one is the Web and the Other a Class Library.
I need to put Entity Framework in the Class Library Project.
However, I am unable to read the Connection String when scaffolding the DB.

1. Initialize Secret: `dotnet user-secrets init`
2. Set item to store: `dotnet user-secrets set "ConnectionStrings:MyConnString" "string"`
3. Scaffold DB: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:MyConnString`

This obviously will not work because the static configuration method is in the web project and not the Class Library project.

Error:
`A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings:APIConnection'  was not found in the application's configuration.`

The only way I can make this work is hardcoding the connection string.

Is there anyway other way to make this work?

Comment: Did you try to set the connection string like this?
`dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings.MyConnection`

Comment: I used a colon instead of a period as explained above but regardless, it does not work as explained above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me in ASP.NET Core 6 and EfCore `v6.0.1`.

Here the steps I've done:

1. Create ASP.NET Core Web API and class lib projects

```
-- > WebApp.Api\
   |
   > WebApp.Data\ 
   |
   > WebApp.sln
```

2. Set connection string secret for `WebApp.Api`. Ensure that `UserSecretsId` is added to csproj `PropertyGroup`:

```
> dotnet user-secrets init
> dotnet user-secrets set "ConnectionStrings:MyConnString" "<conn-string>"
```

3. Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` into `WebApp.Data`. Add project reference from `WebApp.Api` to `WebApp.Data`.
4. Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` nuget for `WebApp.Api` project.
5. In cmd navigate to `WebApp.Api` project folder and run the following command:

```
> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:MyConnString "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" -p ..\WepApp.Data\
```

In that case for the `scaffold` command startup project is `WebApp.Api` and target project is `WebApp.Data`

Comment: Works Perfectly!
Thank you so much!

Comment: For step two, are you within the `WebApp.Api` directory when executing these commands? I would imagine so, otherwise how would `dotnet user-secrets` know which project to create the secrets against?

Comment: @devklick yes, exactly